# How do i parse xml rss feed content in python?

Tags: python, urllib

I have the rss feed from fox news i need to display the title of the articles, and the date and time using tkinter.

```
def fox_news():
    fox_news = download('https://moxie.foxnews.com/google-publisher/latest.xml')
    title = re.compile("title").search(fox_news)
    print(title)
```

Comment: There are probably dozens of ways. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish and what research you've done?

Comment: i was thinking to use regex to display the title and the i have also created the download function which retrives the xml file but i just need to find a way to display its contents

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to try to pull data out of xml-formatted data. There are xml-specific libraries available for python.

Comment: Your title is asking how to _display_ xml rss feed data, but in the comments it sounds like you might actually be asking how to parse the data from xml. Please pick just one of those problems.

Comment: i want to parse sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use **feedparser** library

Just install it: `pip install feedparser`

And everything is ready:

```
import feedparser


def fox_news():
    feed = feedparser.parse('https://moxie.foxnews.com/google-publisher/latest.xml')
    
    for entry in feed.entries:
        title = entry.title
        published = entry.published_parsed
        
        print(published)
        print(title)
        print()


fox_news()
```

Result:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=2, tm_min=0, tm_sec=56, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=298, tm_isdst=0)
Some news title 1

time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=1, tm_min=57, tm_sec=50, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=298, tm_isdst=0)
Some news title 2

time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=1, tm_min=49, tm_sec=18, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=298, tm_isdst=0)
Some news title 3
```